# How to show Dynamic JSON values in Page Source using Next.js version 14

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, next-auth, next.js14

i am using next.js version 14 in app router concept. JSON values are dynamically fetched and shown in component, but JSON values are not getting render in page source.

[I need these JSON values to be fetched in page source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vH31.png)

[Want to Render dynamic values in source page here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INayW.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.